# Exponential Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying for an exam at the moment, and I've got one problem I just can't get past:

> $$ \dot x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -100 & -20\sqrt5 \end{bmatrix} x$$
>   Solve the system and show that any solution $x(t)$ of this system is exponentially convergent to zero.

I had found the solution of this system is

> $$ x(t) = c_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -20+10\sqrt5 \end{bmatrix} exp((-20+10\sqrt5)t) +c_2\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -20-10\sqrt5 \end{bmatrix} exp((-20-10\sqrt5)t) $$

However, I don't know how to show that it is exponentially convergent to zero.

Please help. Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is the variable $t$ in the equation?

Comment: What happens when $t\to \infty$?

Comment: What @Shrey Ayan means is that you should write $ exp((-20 \pm 10\sqrt5)\color{red}{t})$

Comment: Oops, I forgot it! I've just edited!

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-degenerate linear system so you just need to find the eigenvalues of the matrix. As long as both of them are negative, then all solution converges to zero. The eigenvalues of the matrix in your problems are: $-10(\sqrt{5} \pm 2) < 0$.

Comment: I wonder if I should show that this system is non-degenerate?

Comment: That is because you have a two dimensional system with 2 distinct eigenvalues.